# How to create both template version to take an array begin and end (with T* and It) without duplicated code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When i create a function that will take the `begin` and `end` of an array (let's say to create a quick_sort), i have to create the version that takes T*:

```
template<typename T> void quick_sort(T *_beg, T *_end){...}
```

and

```
template<typename It> void quick_sort(It _beg, It _end);
```

So i can use the function in `std::vector` and other containers, and built-in arrays.

But to avoid the duplicated code the only thing that is in the second version is:

```
{
    quick_sort(&*_beg, &*_end);
}
```

Works well... most of the times, but sometimes i get the error

```
can't dereference out of range vector iterator
```

For trying to dereference the `end` iterator (Using the visual studio compiler).

How to develop safetly both versions of this avoiding duplicated code?

Comment: If you look at *all* standard library function taking ranges, they don't have two different overloads or specializations for "arrays" and other iterators. There's only one variant, as pointers are themselves (as mentioned in an answer) iterators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pointer *is an iterator*. So to avoid duplication, just remove the first version entirely, and stick to accepting the abstraction (iterators).

Comment: Correct! I didn't knew a type ```T``` can be ```T*```